# Check User login React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

No **React Navigation 5** não existe mais o **Switch Navigator**. No Doc de Upgrading a solução proposta pra impedir do usuário voltar a tela de login é esse if ternário que verifica se o User está logado.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Mas claro que eu preciso criar essa função **isLoggedIn** mas eu não faço ideia de por onde começar. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: `isLoggedIn` seria uma variável, um `boolean` por exemplo. Provavelmente na sua aplicação você já deve armazenar algo desse tipo no localStorage, um token, algo assim.

Comment: Seria algo mais ou menos assim:
```async function isLoggedIn() {
      // buscando o user_id do localStorage
      const user_id = localStorage.getItem('user');
      
      })```.   ???

Comment: Ai vc teria que retornar algo como `return user_id !== null` para retornar um boolean, acho que funcionaria assim. Eu costumo deixar algumas informações do usuário logado utilizando a Context API, ai eu só verifico se a variável no state é true, dai quando vc faz o logout ele redireciona automático.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa de usar o react-redux para isto ou o react-context.
Ao fazer login na screen de login o servidor deve te encaminhar um token.
 - Armezene o token no localStorage
 - crie uma função que ao ser chamada ele verifica se este token é valido, ou seja, você deve ter um recurso de api no back que receba o token e devolva se ele ainda é valido. Caso sim, esta função retorna um true. Geralmente a gente encaminha com o status loading também que seria enquanto a solicitação está sendo feita. Assim você pode por algum skeleton ou placeholder monstrando que a solicitação está em andamento.
Tem uma explicação muito boa de como fazer isto na documentação.
Segue o link: [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)